# Mysql query delete a DATE that is older than 30 days from another date

Tags: mysql, date

Hello I am trying to create a query that deletes all data that is recorded as being before 2012/11/10 by 30 days. I am not sure how to do this as all I can think of is

```
DELETE FROM fines
WHERE 
fTime < (2012-11-10, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

However this gives me error 1292 incorrect date value

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: use the correct comparison , check how this supported by your database engine.

Comment: @tAmirNaghizadeh do you mean "by MySQL"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
DELETE FROM fines
WHERE 
fTime < ('2012-11-10' - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4099

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 delete from fines where ftime < DATE_SUB("2012-11-10" , INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4100